# Autolayout form login in Xcode 8

Tags: authentication, autolayout, xcode8, ios-autolayout

I have a problem in managing the autolayout of a form of login with these elements
[Form login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGmQY.png)

The elements are an ImageView on the top, two textFields and two buttons in the middle and another button on the bottom.

Does anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Connect username field to be centered horizontal in container and vertical space  between UIImage and leading ,trailing constraints to the view(left and right ,give value to look similar like in photo if you dont have strict size) after just connect all other fields with username field to be equal width and height ,centered horizontal and vertical space between them.Try to make vertical space like in image ,play litle bit try diferent values that match like in form on photo.
"Continue without registration" set center horizontaly and vertical space to bottom layout (vertical space = 16 ,for example)